# Mathematical logic: completeness with respect to the totality of the models/ completeness with respect to any set of models

Tags: logic

The lecture notes on mathematical logic that I'm reading say that the completeness of a theory T with respect to the totality of the models doesn't imply the completeness of T with respect to any set of models. According to the lecture notes, «this becomes evident if one thinks that a closed formula of the langage of T is true in a set of models if it is true in some model of T». The author of the lecture notes contrasts the case of completeness with the case of soundness: «the attribution of soundness without restrictions is more "demanding" than the attribution of soundness with respect to a restricted set of models, as the former implies the latter but the latter doesn't imply the former".

I don't understand how you can have that the completeness of a theory T with respect to the totality of the models doesn't imply the completeness of T with respect to any set of models.

P.S. Definition of a theory in the lecture notes: a set of sentences closed under derivation (i.e., a set of theorems).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that restricting to a set of models can introduce new things that are always true and this is more "demanding". To say $T$ is complete with respect to the totality of the models means that everything that is true in *every* model is provable in $T$. To say $T$ is complete with respect to some set $A$ of models means that everything that is true in every model *in $A$* is provable in $T$.

Say $T$ is the empty theory. $T$ is complete with respect to the totality of models (because every structure is a model of $T$, the only things true in *every* structure are tautologies, and first-order logic is complete). Let $A$ be the set $\{M\}$, where $M$ is the model consisting of exactly one element. In $M$, it is the case that "there is exactly one object". So in every structure in $A$, the sentence "there is exactly one object" is true. But $T$ does not prove "there is exactly one object", because there are models of $T$ that have more than one object.

The observation you mention, "this becomes evident if one thinks that a closed formula of the language of $T$ is true in a set of models if it is true in some model of $T$", is referring to this: if there is any sentence $T$ doesn't prove which is true in some model $M$ of $T$, then $T$ is automatically incomplete with respect to the set of models $\{M\}$.